# Unable Post tweet From C# Aaplication

Tags: c#, twitter

i'm using oauth and twitterizer in my C# apps, and after trying for several times. and it won't get any exception, error. but it's doesn't want to post it to twitter.

here is my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BLTgUser objBLTgUser = new BLTgUser();
    if (!objBLTgUser.IsLogin) objBLTgUser.GoToLoginPage(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    m_strIdGods = objBLTgUser.IdGods;

    BLGodsProfile objGods = new BLGodsProfile();
    tbmgodsprofile objGodsProfile = objGods.GetGodsByIdGods(m_strIdGods);

    string reqToken = Request.QueryString["oauth_token"].ToString();
    string pin = Request.QueryString["oauth_verifier"].ToString();

    var oauth_consumerKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterConsumerKey"];
    var oauth_consumerSecret = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterConsumerSecret"];

    var tokens = OAuthUtility.GetAccessToken(
                oauth_consumerKey,
                oauth_consumerSecret,
                reqToken,
                pin);

    string accessToken = tokens.Token;
    string accessTokenSecret = tokens.TokenSecret;


    objGodsProfile.twittertoken = accessToken;
    objGodsProfile.twitterpin = accessTokenSecret;
    objGodsProfile.twitterstatus = "1";

    objGods.UpdateGodsProfile(objGodsProfile);
}
```

i'm trying store the token and tokensecret to Database, it's for the next uses.

```
string v_str = "";
    BLEnumHelper m_BLEnumHelper = new BLEnumHelper();
    BLGodsProfile userprofile = new BLGodsProfile();
    tbmgodsprofile godsAccessToken = userprofile.GetGodsByIdGods(m_strIdGods);

    string reqToken = godsAccessToken.twittertoken;
    string reqTokenAccess = godsAccessToken.twitterpin;

    var oauth_consumerKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterConsumerKey"];
    var oauth_consumerSecret = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterConsumerSecret"];

    OAuthTokens accesstoken = new OAuthTokens()
    {
        AccessToken = reqToken,
        AccessTokenSecret = reqTokenAccess ,
        ConsumerKey = oauth_consumerKey,
        ConsumerSecret = oauth_consumerSecret 
    };

    TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> response = TwitterStatus.Update(accesstoken,p_strMessage);
    if (response.Result == RequestResult.Success)
    {
        Response.Write("we did it!");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("it's all bad.");
    }
```

and after the 2nd code be called, it wont' post to twitter.

Comment: Please try to specify your issue, not just "it's doesn't want to post it to twitter".

Comment: the issue is I can't post to twitter, even though i've already got the token and tokensecret, which i've store it to my database.

Answer (score 0):

Twitterizer is no longer maintained.

https://github.com/Twitterizer/Twitterizer/blob/develop/README.mediawiki

Twitterizer not supporting Twitter's new API version 1.1, you can't use it for development.

As an alternative, I recommend [CoreTweet](https://github.com/CoreTweet/CoreTweet) for you.